# Can't reach my audio src to play it with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5-audio

I'm doing a test and i want to start a mp3 file with jQuery, i tried many options and it seems that i can't achieve to do it :

Here is my html :

```
 <td><span class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn_player" href="http://www.uscis.gov/files/nativedocuments/Track%2093.mp3" id="player">
                        <audio id="audio" controls style="display:none"><source src='http://www.uscis.gov/files/nativedocuments/Track%2093.mp3'></audio>
                        <i class="fad fa-play">
                        </i></span></td>
```

as you can see i tried many options

my Jquery code :

```
$('.btn_player').click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
console.log('button audio player clicked');
document.getElementById("audio").play;
});
```

The btn click action the console.log but don't play any file

here is a test page to see my problem

```js
$('.btn_player').click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
console.log('button audio player clicked');
document.getElementById("audio").play;
});
```

```css
.test {
background-color: green;
width: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class='test'>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn_player" href="http://www.uscis.gov/files/nativedocuments/Track%2093.mp3" id="player">play me
                            <audio id="audio" controls style="display:none"><source src='http://www.uscis.gov/files/nativedocuments/Track%2093.mp3'></audio>
                            <i class="fad fa-play">
                            </i></span></div>
```

Comment: `.play`- that's not how you _call_ a function/method in JavaScript; missing the `()`.

Comment: @CBroe i corrected but still can't play the audio element

Comment: Works fine for me here, https://jsfiddle.net/mc1dsk4t/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.btn_player').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('button audio player clicked');
    document.getElementById("audio").play();
    });

    });
```

```css
.test {
background-color: green;
width: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-aVKKRRi/Q/YV+4mjoKBsE4x3H+BkegoM/em46NNlCqNTmUYADjBbeNefNxYV7giUp0VxICtqdrbqU7iVaeZNXA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <div class='test'>

<span class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn_player" href="http://www.uscis.gov/files/nativedocuments/Track%2093.mp3" id="player">play me
                            <audio id="audio" controls style="display:none"><source src='http://www.uscis.gov/files/nativedocuments/Track%2093.mp3'></audio>
                            <i class="fad fa-play">
                            </i></span></div>
```

Missing play()

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('.btn_player').click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
console.log('button audio player clicked');
document.getElementById("audio").play();
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-aVKKRRi/Q/YV+4mjoKBsE4x3H+BkegoM/em46NNlCqNTmUYADjBbeNefNxYV7giUp0VxICtqdrbqU7iVaeZNXA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-aVKKRRi/Q/YV+4mjoKBsE4x3H+BkegoM/em46NNlCqNTmUYADjBbeNefNxYV7giUp0VxICtqdrbqU7iVaeZNXA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<div class='test'>
```

play me

Comment: it works fine with controls but i don't want to use it i want the button to be the launcher not controls

Comment: try again..it works